# VMWare shared folder git pull tips from the remote, but no such ref was fetched

Tags: git, vmware, shared, pull, fuse

When I do `git pull` in VMWare shared folder,

```bash
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/dev' from the remote, 
but no such ref was fetched.
```

Then I do `git fetch -v`, `git merge origin/master`, they work well.

```bash
-> git:(dev) git fetch -v
From https://code.github.com/dev/ent.com
 = [up to date]      dev        -> origin/dev
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master

-> git:(dev) git merge origin/dev
Already up to date.
```

I try `git pull` in windows,no problem, also in VMWare ubuntu22.04.

```bash
Already up to date.
```

And I try to find the problem from internet, but no useful.

Some Information:

> VMware® Workstation 16 Pro: 16.2.4 build-20089737

```
➜  ~ vmhgfs-fuse -V
vmhgfs-fuse: version 1.6.12.0

FUSE library version 3.10.5
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.31
fusermount3 version: 3.10.5
```

Comment: Looks like Yet Another Problem With Shared Folders. Don't use them (at least not with Git), as they're full of bugs. I have had similar mystery problems in similar (not the same) systems.

Comment: I need this function , when I use `vmware-tools-patches` will solved this problem,but will take more other problem, it is too old for new version vmware.

Comment: I correct my statement，`git pull` command work well in git repository which not in ubuntu22.04 vmware shared fold.